# How to change material a sfa file?

Tags: android, arcore

I have a single model and I want to change image of it.
with below codes I can render my model (sfb file):

```
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, sfb_source])
                .build()
                .thenAccept(renderable -> this.renderable = renderable)
                .exceptionally(
                        throwable -> {
                            Toast toast =
                                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load andy renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                            toast.show();
                            return null;
                        });
```

Now, my model is unique. but I have multi images(with same sizes).
I should create multi sfb files or is there any ways to load them and change it in real time?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it is worth mentioning that Scene form is deprecated, or more accurately  'open sourced and archived', in case you are building on it which I think you might be from your code - see note here: https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop.

You can still work with the older versions or open version of Sceneform - this may be ok for your use case.

Either way, for your requirements it sounds like you have two options:

- use a model which support animation - Sceneform based instructions here: https://developers.google.com/sceneform/develop/animation
- delete and replace the model when you want to change it - this is not as slow as it sounds and can, in my experience, look fairly seamless when changing model colours etc (at least in Sceneform based apps - not tried with OpenGL and ARCore).